# Log4J conversion specifier "%l" not printing the whole stack trace

Tags: java, log4j, smtpappender, mdc

I am trying to send an email in case error occurs in our project. For this we are using Log4j's `SMTPAppender`. I am running my project in the development mode and trying to get the full stack trace of the error by using following `ConversionPattern` in `SMTPAppender` :

```xml
<param name="ConversionPattern" 
    value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%t] [%5p] [%c ] %n %m %l %X{config}"/>
```

I am throwing error as follows:

```
try {
  throw new Exception(" To get the MDC values !!!");
} catch (Exception e)
{
  LOGGER.error(" To get the MDC values !!!", e);
}
```

`%m` is replaced by the text `To get the MDC values !!!`  but `%l` (*lower-case `L`*) is printing the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing the logging request with line number (just like %c do, with one difference that %c never prints the line number while %l does).

What could be the correct way to get the stack trace and why `%l` is not getting the whole stack trace ?

Comment: Based on our comment conversation under my old answer, I've adjusted your question and hopefully someone will have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

%l is used to output location information of the caller which generated the logging event.
it si snot print whole stacktrace.
you can add these lines of code in your catch block.

```
catch (Exception e) {
            CharArrayWriter cw = new CharArrayWriter();
            PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(cw);
            e.printStackTrace(w);
            w.close();
            String trace = cw.toString();
     LOGGER.error(" To get the MDC values !!!",trace);
}
```